# Image as Plane and Stroke Object - transparency issue

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil

Need help to fix the stroke overlapping on the hand image, which is added as *Images as Plane*.

[image]

Comment: move a bit image object in Z axis?

Comment: I tried, but still its as transparent

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to fix curve appearance, problem lies in imported *Image as Plane* that is by default set with *Alpha Blend* type.

- Select Image object
- go to *Material Properties > Settings* panel
- change **Blend Mode > Alpha Clip**

[image]